# Problem on parabola from conics

Tags: algebra-precalculus

An arch-shaped monument is often mistak- 
en to be parabolic in shape. In fact, it is a catenary, which has 
a more complicated formula than a parabola.The arch is 475 
feet high and 444 feet wide at its base. Complete parts (a), 
(b), and (c).

(a) Find the equation of a parabola with the same 
dimensions. Let x equal the horizontal distance from the 
center of the arc.

(b) The table gives the height of the arch at various widths; 
find the corresponding heights for the parabola found in 
(a).
Width(ft).    Hight

1. 417         100
2. 354          237.5
3. 248          375

C) Do the data support the notion that the arch is a parabola?

Comment: I am quite worry for you due to your emojis.

Comment: It's nothing serious. I am self studying precalculus. I'm just really frustrated with this problem 

Comment: Can you please edit your post and add your attempts at solving this problem? By the way, do take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) (in particular, show what you tried to do), use the [formatting help](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and write your equations in [LaTeX / MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) to make things easier to read.

Comment: Hint: Write down the Parbola equation. See if the data you have results in parameters that are real. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola and http://www.jimahoffman.com/MathC30/Parabola/parabola.htm

Comment: This [link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30116/597056) may be helpful ;)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the base of the parabola to be y= 0 and take x= 0 at the center of the base.  Then the parabola is of the form $y= ax^2+ b$ for some numbers, a and b.  We need to find the values of a and b.  The base is 444 feet wide so two points on the parabola are (222, 0) and (-222,0).  Putting either of those into the formula gives the equation $0= a(222)^2+ b= 49284a+ b$.  The arch is 475 feet high so a third point on the parabola is (0, 475).  Putting that into the formula gives the equation 475= a(0^2)+ b= b.  So b= 475 and then 49283a+ 475= 0.  49283a= -475, and a= -475/49283.

The equation of the parabola is y= (-475/49283)x^2+ 475.

Now put x= 208.5, y= 100;  x= 177, y= 237.5; x= 124, y= 375 (x is half the given widths) into that equation.  Do they satisfy it?  If not, how far are the off?